# I have removed all mail accounts from my iPhone and reset it. What's using storage?

Tags: iphone, storage, mobile-mail

I have deleted all my e-mail accounts from Mail from the iPhone -- iCloud, my work account, etc., and have reset the phone (powering off and then back on) a couple of times.

In Settings/General/Storage, I still show 186 MB of data being used by mail. Is the Mail app itself 186 MB? If not, how can I free up some of the space being "used" when there are no accounts at all on the phone?

Comment: Do a hard reset - press and hold Home and Sleep until the Apple logo appears. Data is usually not fully deleted until the device is reset. Alternatively it may be cached information that Mail is hanging onto, but that should be removed when the associated email account is removed.

Comment: Now shows as 174 MB, which is... different, but far from reassuring.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this and spent a whole day trying to figure out why my mail app on my iphone suddenly took up 2.5.gigabytes of storage!  I did all of the suggestions on various websites to no avail.  I did however finally FIX IT.  I deleted all of my mail accounts and then DELTED THE MAIL APP.  Presto!  This seemed to be the key to fix the problem.  I was able to recover 2.5 gigs of storage back to my 16gb iphone.   I then reinstalled the mail app and started over again.  This seemed to work for me.  Another thing to try is to download one of the many (and good) third party email apps.  Hope this helps you all.
-Patty

Answer (score 0):

Took a look at my storage settings and can see that mine is using 179 MB of space with all my accounts still in there so I'm guessing that you are correct about it being mostly application.

Unfortunately, I don't think you can get rid of the app if the phone is not jailbroken so if you are running out of space, which I guess is the issue, then you will have to look elsewhere for room.

Have you check the Camera Roll in that area? That is usually a big culprit of being a space hog. I upload my photos to Google+ to back them up and delete them from my phone regularly. Not the best solution but keeps the phone memory usage low.

Comment: I think I'm doubting your 179MB figure being mostly the application. It is bundled with iOS and Apple doesn't show the size of other bundled apps (although it shows the size of the contents stored within the app). My iPhone shows 11.4MB for Mail and when I tap it, it shows "Mail and Attachments" = 11.4MB.

Answer (score -1):

in iPhone go to Settings->General->Storage&iCloudUsage->Storage->ManageStorage.  and see what is using storage.